# how to remove tick from people picker?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, people-picker

In the people picker control comes with the default sharepoint form has a tick image to resolve the name and book icon to select the users.

how do i remove the tick icon and keep the book icon to pick users.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can hide that tick icon by jQuery:

```
$('a[title="Check Names"]').hide();
```

You can inspect the same element and make sure the `title` attribute of the `a` tag must be `Check Names`.

If it is a different then you can simply use that text in above snippet.

It is also possible with CSS. All you need is wrapper CSS Class and refer that class and apply below CSS:

```
.wrapper-class a[title="Check Names"] { display: none; }
```

Note that `wrapper-class` is just for reference, you should your given class in that CSS.
Hope this helps!